# creating a set of consecutive non-overlapping bounds from a larger given bounds

Tags: python, boundary

If a bound is given as (40,260) and it needs to be divided into 4 equal smaller consecutive non-overlapping bounds (i.e.,(40,95),(96,150),(151,205),(206,260))
I tried the following method.

```
def range_non_overlapping(range_left, range_right, range_per_cut, cut_num)  
    ranges=[]
    for i in range(cut_num):
            ranges.append(range_left + i * range_per_cut)
            ranges.append(min(range_right, (range_left + (i + 1) * range_per_cut))) 
    return ranges
```

But the following code results in overlapping regions on the boundaries [40,95,95,150,150,205,205,260] (pairs from the beginning of the list is a smaller bound). I need to create [40,95,96,150,151,205,206,260]

Comment: StackOverflow isn’t a code-writing service so you should edit your honet attempt to solve this into you question as a [mre]

Comment: my apologies. I modified the question with more information @barny

Comment: No, your code still isn’t a [mre]. Try pasting the code literally as it is in your question into a file and running it; does it produce the output you show in the question? Not providing a [mre] is reducing your chances of getting real help. Read [ask].

Comment: It does shows the output I mentioned and I already got the help I was looking for @barny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
def chunknize(start, stop, num):
    step = (stop - start) / num
    return [
        (start + i * step + (0 if i == 0 else 1),
        start + (i + 1) * step)
        for i in range(num)]
    
print(chunknize(40, 260, 4))
# [(40.0, 95.0), (96.0, 150.0), (151.0, 205.0), (206.0, 260.0)]
```

Comment: What if the bound is (1, 100, 5)?   - Got [(1, 20), (21, 39), (40, 58), (59, 77), (78, 96)] Or if still use float div. / --- then the results: [(1.0, 20.8), (21.8, 40.6), (41.6, 60.400000000000006), (61.400000000000006, 80.2), (81.2, 100.0)]

Comment: @DanielHao You got this result because you're using integer divison. Try using the float division.

Answer (score 1):

If the endpoints are inclusive, then you can't get 4 equal regions, because the size (221) is not a multiple of 4.  I would argue that you want (40,94), (95,149), (150,204), (205,260)), which you can do by:

```
def divide( left, right, cuts ):
    delta = (right-left+1) // cuts
    out = []
    for i in range(cuts):
        out.append( left )
        left += delta
        out.append( left - 1 )
    out[-1] = right
    return out

print( divide( 40, 260, 4 ) )
```

Those regions are 55, 55, 55, and 56.